# Are there advantages to testing accessors separately?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

If I were to have a class with a property on it should I be testing the get and set functionalities separately or together?

```
class MyObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[TestClass]
class MyObjectTests
{
    MyObject subject

    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInitialize()
    {
        subject = new MyObject();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test_Name()
    {
        string value = "TestValue";
        subject.Name = value;
        Assert.AreEqual(value, subject.Name);
    }
}
```

In the example above both the getter and setter are being called, so the test passing depends on them both functioning correctly.

Another option could be to test them in different tests, to do this I could set the property via reflection while testing the getter and vice versa. Something like this perhaps.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test_Name()
{
    string value = "TestValue";

    var field = typeof(MyObject).GetField("<Name>k__BackingField", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    field.SetValue(subject, value);

    Assert.AreEqual(value, subject.Name);
}
```

But does this have any real advantages?

I'm torn between the idea that a test should only test a single piece of functionality and the complexities and overhead of using reflection like this over and over throughout my code-base.

Obviously in this example the property is as simple as it possibly could be, but in a class when a setter is actually performing business logic, can/should the tests also rely on the getter? What if they're both performing business logic?

Should I be testing complex accessors with reflection and testing simpler ones together? But what if the simple ones change down the road?

Comment: To me this seems fairly pointless, how the property's value is being stored should not be a concern.  You should only be testing the observable behavior.  If you were to refactor your code to use a private field for storage instead, the observable behavior doesn't change yet you have to update a bunch of failing unit tests.

Answer (score 3):

> Are there advantages to testing accessors separately?

Sure, like any test there are advantages in making your tests more granular. When they fail, it's clearer about what broke them reducing the time spent debugging test failures. Smaller tests also tend to be easier to write, and easier to write *correctly* since they tend to be less complex.

That said, the advantages aren't always worth it. More tests in general mean more time to write, run, and maintain. If the properties are simple, then the likelihood of them being broken is small and the cost if they do break might not be worth testing.

Like most testing approaches, it's up to you to weigh the risk involved and make a judgement call about how much risk you're willing to tolerate given the various costs to mitigate it.

Comment: +1 for "the advantages aren't always worth it".  For most getter/setters, the "advantages" of separate tests are almost never worth it.

Comment: well, when they're not trivial getter/setters they're often worth it. But non-trivial getter/setters are (imo) to be avoided, but that's not _quite_ expert consensus enough to be a good answer I think.

Comment: It's not uncommon for a setter to validate the input, or to notify about the value change.  Non-trivial setters aren't uncommon, in my experience.  Trivial getters of the form `return m_lastName` are relatively common.

Comment: @user949300: I agree with you, but isn't the main reason for that conclusion that getters and setters should not be using non-trivial logic to begin with? Trivially readable logic does not warrant testing, and if you keep your getters and setters trivially readable (which you should), then they clearly don't need to be tested anyway.

Comment: @NickAlexeev: Input validation or value change notification is easily testable behavior though. You don't actually need access to the internal get/set logic itself, these tests only require you to observe the external behavior of the object whose property you're getting/setting.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your simple example

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

I'd argue that the whole test is pointless. It would just test the (.NET) framework and not your own code.

Testing properties at all should only be done if they do have some behaviour that goes beyond merely storing and reading a value, some validation logic for example. Let's look at such a property:

```
public string MyProperty
{
    get
    {
        return _myProperty;
    }
    set
    {
        // Do some validation here
        _myProperty = value;
    }
}
private string _myProperty;
```

If you test `get` and `set` seperately with your reflection method, what would you really test? You would not only test the behaviour of the property but also an unimportant implementation detail. If for whatever reason `_myProperty` would be renamed, your test suddenly would break even though the behaviour of the property didn't change.

Comment: **(1)** OP specifically mentioned that the question is about complex properties with actual business logic in the getter and setter. **(2)** Even with reflection, you can have refactor-friendly property names by using the `nameof()` operator ([link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/nameof), take special note of the `INotifyPropertyChanged` key use case as it's directly applicable to this scenario)

Comment: @Flater (1) I know, I only used the simple example to illustrate the point of not testing framework/language features, something you mention in your answer yourself. (2) `nameof()` won't help here. `_myProperty` is `private` and therefore not in scope in the test method.

Answer (score 1):

> Obviously in this example the property is as simple as it possibly could be,

Just to get it out of the way: trivially readable code does not require testing. When you test down to this level, you are effectively testing the framework/language you're using, which is not your responsibility to test. This is effectlively as useful as `Assert.AreEqual(1+1, 2)`, which is to say that it isn't useful testing.

> but in a class when a setter is actually performing business logic, can/should the tests also rely on the getter? What if they're both performing business logic?
>
> I'm torn between the idea that a test should only test a single piece of functionality

You're correct, but it's a bit counterintuitive that you hold to this notion while you are also implementing a property's getter *and* setter with complex and non-abstracted (therefore not separately testable) business logic.

As I said, trivially readable code should not be tested. If you follow that, then your question implies that your getter and setter are both implementing non-trivial logic.

I think you're stacking way too much logical complexity in this property's getters and setters. You're noticing this now because it reduces testability, but it should've thrown up a red flag earlier than that.

Think of it this way: by having complex logic in both the getter and setter, you are effectively doing a *secret conversion* of your data. For example:

```
public class Foo
{
    private string mySecretValue;

    public int MyInt
    {
        get { return Convert.ToInt32(mySecretValue); }
        set { mySecretValue = value.ToString(); }
    }
}
```

This means that anyone who uses this object **doesn't need to care** about this secret conversion. As long as the conversion is symmetrical, the test should always pass, even if I change the conversion logic. For example, let's say I have the following test:

```
var foo = new Foo() { MyInt = 123 };

Assert.AreEqual(123, foo.MyInt);
```

This test would currently pass. And suppose I change my code:

```
public class Foo
{
    private string mySecretValue;

    public int MyInt
    {
        get { return Convert.ToInt32(mySecretValue).Replace("ZERO", 0); }
        set { mySecretValue = value.ToString().Replace(0, "ZERO"); }
    }
}
```

**The test should still pass, because the consumer of the `Foo` object does not care about the conversion logic**. It only cares about the fact that the conversion is symmetrical, which it still is.

Never forget that **tests only care about external behavior**. Private logic is by definition private and therefore not needed to be shared outside of the class (which means the test itself cannot rely on knowing a class' private logic).

It shouldn't matter what happens under the hood. As long as it walks like a duck, floats like a duck, and quacks like a duck, ***it's a duck***. Even if under the hood (i.e. in the private logic) it's just a team of miniature people operating a duck-suit.

> Should I be testing complex accessors with reflection and testing simpler ones together?

The long and short of it is that you shouldn't have complex accessors. If a bit of logic is less than trivial (and thus valid to test), it should be abstracted into a method of its own. The property can still call the method, and you can write a test which tests that method, without actually needing to worry about the actual property itself.

Besides, who says that this logic wouldn't be useful in more than one property? It makes no sense to make this non-trivial logic not reusable by only keeping it in the property's get/set accessor.

> But what if the simple ones change down the road?

As a general rule of thumb, when things change, then you write tests for the no-longer-simple things.

It's a pitfall to think that you should write all of your tests now so they can be used in perpetuity without any further changes or expansions.
Codebases evolve, complexities appear and disappear, and your test suite needs to adapt to these changes as well. Otherwise, your tests are growing apart from the codebase they're supposed to be testing.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason not to test getters or setters separately or not testing them at all.

When you test behaviour of the class or function where getters and setters are used you will test getters and setter automatically. So having dedicated tests for getters and setters become redundant.

Unit tests provide confidence to the developer and safety net for refactoring. 
With separated tests for getters and setters refactoring will become a nightmare, because you will be forced to rewrite tests every time you add remove properties.

Comment: but... that's the point. There's a reason we write many unit tests rather than one big integration test that covers everything.

Comment: Surely if an accessor has business logic within it then it testing it would be testing behavior?

Comment: @Telastyn, I am not talking about integration tests. For unit tests you will mock up all external resources which makes tests slow and possibly mock up dependencies which are very very very complicated to configure produce very very big amount of test cases.

Comment: @Telastyn, in addition: if one big integration test *covers everything* (usually very rare case) and executes fast enough to provide quick feedback during development - I will be more than happy to have it instead of bunch of unit tests with mocked dependencies. 
Because I will be able to change my internal design and test will tell me in a seconds did I break something.

Comment: but not _what_ you broke.

Comment: @TobySmith, if logic of setter can be tested through the tests for the consumer of the setter, than you don't need to write dedicated tests for setter. If not and logic is very complicated, then write unit test for setter to get confidence that code is working.

Comment: @Telastyn, true, integration tests do not provide straightforward indication of what is the actual reason of failed test. You can improve it by using assertions with more detailed failed message but sometimes it can lead in a wrong direction and next step after failed test will be debugging of the failed test.

Comment: This answer hinges on an _"A implicitly tests B and C so don't bother testing B and C"_ mentality, which is quite the opposite of how you should be writing tests. When A passes, you may have implicitly proven that A B and C pass, sure. But when A fails, what failed? A? B? C? The point of a test is so you know exactly _which_ part failed (even if you don't don't exactly know why). Tests are written so that their failure is informative to the developer. With this approach, you only know whether a problem exists or not, but not which part is actually causing a problem, which is not informative.

Comment: When you apply this mentality to testing, you're effectively stating that unit tests for components that are used in integration tests are rendered wholly obsolete, since the success of the integration test confirms the correct behavior of all involved components. It's alluring to write less tests because no one likes writing them; but when you start undercutting the benefit of actually having tests (= informative failures), then you're really just doing the leg work without reaping the benefits, which is wasted effort. Don't do this.

Comment: @Flater, your orthodox comments dropped out downsides of writing tests for every class method. When starting to work on the feature you don't know what components will participate in the solution, so you will write tests against feature's boundaries, by mocking those boundaries and will write simplest and dirtiest implementation just to make tests pass. After all scenarios are tested and implemented you can see whole implementation and see how this code can be refactored to make it more maintainable and readable by introducing new components or reusing already existed ones.

Comment: @Flater, with orthodox rule to test every class method, you end up with a code where obvious refactoring will be difficult(or not bother) to do, because you will be forced to rewrite tests of components you changed, even where the change didn't change a behaviour.

Comment: Tests are written based on the expected behavior, not the specific implementation. If you refactor your code but retain its behavior; then the tests don't need to be refactored. If you end up changing the behavior of your core logic halfway through development, that would presumably be an _unexpected_ change (which you obviously cannot anticipate when you write your tests). Because if it's not unexpected, then you've either started developing before you know what the solution needed to do; or you've written tests that test the _implementation_ and not the external behavior.

Comment: In essence, just because Tommy felt sick and decided to take all the medicine he could find, which was a bad decision; does not mean that taking medicine by itself is a bad decision. Based on your issues with the alleged downsides of writing tests, it seems like you've been writing tests that simply focus on the wrong thing (the implementation, as proven when you said `you will be forced to rewrite tests of components you changed, even where the change didn't change a behaviour`); which is not a valid downside of writing tests in general, it's just a consequence of badly writing tests.

Comment: As a basic example, suppose we define a duck as something that quacks and floats. Therefore, we can test for duckness by testing if the object floats and quacks (two tests). Even if we end up building many different would-be-ducks that are built completely differently, **the test logic does not change**.  `you will be forced to rewrite tests of components you changed, even where the change didn't change a behaviour` This doesn't make sense. If your test is testing something other than behavior, then you're no testing the right thing. E.g. it doesn't matter if the would-be-duck eats bird seed.

Comment: ... because we defined a duck as "something that quacks and floats", not "something that quacks, floats and eats bird seed". If the definition of a duck (= your domain logic) changes, then of course you have to adapt your tests. There is no way around that. But when the definition of a duck does not change, only the 
 specific implementation of would-be-ducks changes; then good tests would not need to be changed at all. Your suggestion is to not write (some) tests so you can avoid having to adjust (some) tests at a later point, which is not a good approach in any way, shape or form.

Comment: @Flater, sorry but nice analogy gone little bid wrong from the beginning, because by `you will be forced to rewrite tests...` I was describing a scenario where you write tests for every class and mock them when testing a consumer of those classes. Mocking will force you to rewrite tests every time you change contracts between components without changing the behaviour. Every time you mock dependencies you are testing implementation details. TLDR, Mock as less as possible.

Comment: @Fabio: A change in the contract **is** a behavioral change. When behavior doesn't change, the way classes consume each other doesn't change, and thus the tests do not need to be rewritten. At best, you may need to supply different test values, but the logic of the test should be preserved for as long as the behavior remains the same. Since unit tests focus on testing a contract (or, more accurately, the implementation thereof), it's obvious that when a contract changes, so do its related tests. You cannot avoid (or anticipate) that.

Comment: @Flater, agree, but I am talking about contracts of lower level classes. Example: I am testing method of class `OrderService.CreateFor(customer)` - I will write a tests which will test behavior of creating a order for the customer. I will test that order returned from the this method will have expected values, I will test that method will throw an exception when given customer is invalid. And if `OrderSerice` class uses some other classes under the hood(validation for example) - I will not test them explicitly, because I am already checked they are working within tests for the `OrderService`

Comment: `And if OrderSerice class uses some other classes under the hood(validation for example) - I will not test them explicitly, because I am already checked they are working within tests for the OrderService` Which brings me back to the earlier point: when your `OrderService` test fails, you have no way of knowing whether the service itself or the underlying validation contains the error. The validation may warrant its own tests, based on if the validation is complex enough to be considered a separate responsibility (which I infer it is, from your phrasing).

Comment: @Flater, I will have tests for expected exception and for expected values, test which fails will tell me where implementation failed. If there no validations tests for expecting validations will fail.